# testng: ant build fails complaining that the java version 1.7 is required

Tags: ant, testng

I'm building the testng jar using ant. during build it complains saying that it requires java 1.7, but i have java 1.8 installed and the JAVA_HOME is set. When i do a java -version, it says i have 1.8 installed.

[image]

This is the target within the build xml that says prompts the message

```
<target name="validate" description="Validates the build environment.">
<!-- java greater than 1.6 required to build -->
<condition property="requiredJavaVersion">
  <or>
    <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.9" />
    <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.8" />
    <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.7" />
  </or>
</condition>
<fail unless="requiredJavaVersion"
      message="Java version 1.7 required." />
<!-- validate ant version too ... -->
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the first line in the output saying unable to locate tools.jar. Resolve that first. I think you need to set your java home properly.

Comment: resolved tools.jar. 
Error persists.
Java_Home is set. i set it again to make sure i didn't mess it up.